# Java Recursion: Determine how many numbers in an array is greater than index 1

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Whole problem:
Given an array A indexed from 1 to n containing integers, determine how many integers in A[1 to n] are greater than A[1]

What i've wrote so far:

```
static int numGreater(int A[], int n, int count)
{
    if(A[1] == A[n])
    {
        return count; 
    }
    else 
    {
        count = (A[1] < A[n] ? count : + 1);
        return numGreater(A, n - 1, count);
    }
}
```

Kinda got stumped. Still new to coding in recursions.

Comment: What's stumping you? Errors? I can see a few logical errors.

Comment: What is the `if` expression supposed to do, and why do you think *that* expression does that?

Comment: Is that the required method signature or did you come up with it? I would try to think how to do it without passing count around; might help to think recursively.

Comment: Sorry if my code is a bit illogical. The if condition should stop the repetition of the method when the int n equates to the first index.

Comment: What's stumping me so far is that I couldn't retain my "count" value without it returning to 0 everytime the else condition is called.

Comment: You don't have to retain a count. You can accumulate the count through recursion. You don't want to use that condition unless you know for certain there aren't any dups in the array so, what would be a good base case if you started at the beginning and went to the end? And how would you gather the count once you got there?

Comment: I've been playing around with where I should initialize my count variable, but i haven't had luck thinking on where it should really go.
I'm a bit new to coding in general, and is still learning the basics and stuff. This site has helped me immensely, but sometimes I just get stumped on ideas on what to do.

Comment: That's fine, but try to answer the questions I asked. 1) is it a requirement to pass count as a parameter? 2) what would be the stopping condition if you were to start comparing A[1] and A[2] *first* and iterating towards the end? 3) how would you `return` the accumulated count? Hint: this solution should not be long.

Comment: Why is recursion requested in this case? It doesn't really make the algorithm more "elegant" or readable than a simple for loop in this situation and it will be far less performant.

Comment: I know right, but in the end, learning how to do it is better than not trying to. I've already done it through iteration, but its better if I could learn how to do it in recursion.

Comment: Learning to force recursion into algorithms that don't require it just teaches you how to write incomprehensible code. Try summing a binary tree or something instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally got it. Problem is that, well, I know there's a way that I dont have to put "count" on the parameters, but I don't know how to. What I did was.

```
static int numGreater(int A[], int n, int count)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        count = A[1] < A[n] ? count + 1 : count;
    return numGreater(A, n - 1, count);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this, and I still want to know them to broaden my understanding on recursions. Further answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Good job figuring it out on your own!

Comment: Thanks man. :D i'll still try to do what you suggested before. The one that doesn't need a "count" in the parameters. Thanks for the help too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've answered it yourself, I'll add my 2-bits with a little visual explanation on how you can avoid retaining the count in a variable and passing it as a parameter in your recursive method.

*Discalimer: I'm using Java's array indexing convention since problem statements like yours may not be language specific and indexing a Java array from 1-n as opposed to 0-(n-1) makes little sense due to the extra elements required to do so. With that said, I assume they mean an array consists of n elements which fill the array. I also start at the beginning of the array and work towards the end; there's no difference in this regard because in either case the stack unwinds to return the value to the caller.*

My crude drawing below is pretty self-explanatory. The `|_..._|`s show the values that are being compared with the associated recursive method calls. On the first call we check for the base case and if not met we call the method again with the next index; we continue to do so until we reach the base case (`n == A.length`). Once we reach the end we return `0` to the previous call which returns its value plus the next call's value (the ongoing count). We continue doing this until we return to the caller.

```
    0     1     2     3 : indices
    -------------------
    3     5     3     6 : values
    |_____|     |     |
    |___________|     |
    |_________________|
<--------2| <--1| <--1| <--0| : return values
    -------------------------
          1     2     3     4 : call stack (4 = base case)
```

Here's the code that does just that:

```
static int numGreater(int[] A, int n) {
    if (n == A.length) return 0;
    return (A[0] < A[n] ? 1 : 0) + count(A, n + 1);
}
```

Now you should be able to see that each method call that is not the base case will add `1` or `0` to the next call based on the `A[0] < A[n]` condition thereby accumulating the count as the stack unwinds making the count variable unnecessary.

Note that you should also be able to see why checking for equality between the first and *i-th* element will not work due to the fact it could short circuit the recursion resulting in an incorrect count.

Comment: Somehow I got it. xD I don't know how to explain it myself, but I got it still. I'll probably shift towards working to the end starting from the first index, rather than the one I did. I think most people would read the code easier that way. Thank you for you're answer sir. One question though, with what you said about indexing an array. Is it better to index an array starting from 1-n or 0-n? English isn't my first language so I kinda didnt get that lone statement. Sorry.

Comment: @Emanhero, it's best to follow the language. Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html); the first thing discussed is the indexing of an array in Java. Doing `A[n]` on an array with `n` elements will result in an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) since the indices go from 0 to (n-1).

Answer (score 0):

Terminate: if `n` is less than 2 - you have nothing to compare.

Recursive step: if `A[n] > A[1]` add 1 to the result and call recursive function.

```
static int numGreater(int A[], int n)
{
    if (n < 2) return 0;
    return A[n] > A[1] 
        ? 1 + numGreater(A, n - 1)
        : numGreater(A, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: `return (A[n] > A[1] ? 1 : 0) + numGreater(A, n - 1);`; DRY.

Comment: That is your rightful opinion which I disagree with. But it wasn't a matter of readability but a matter of needless repetition.

Comment: ok, let me be more clear: `?:` usage as an intermediate step of computation is bad practice. And it's not only my opinion.

Comment: I don't see how that added clarity to your readability claim. Either way, your claim(s) will remain opinion until you back them up with an authoritative source not based on opinion. Doesn't matter if you can show that 1, 100, or 1k people share your opinion because I can do the same; it's still opinion. Saying your snippet has needless repetition by calling the same method twice with the same arguments is *fact*.